# unable to detect newly added lun in rhel4

Tags: linux, rhel

Unable to detect newly added lun in RHEL4 running with 2.6.9-103.ELsmp..Tried LIP protocol but that didn't helped

echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/hostx/issue_lip

Any help is appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

With this version of RHEL, you should be able to install a package called `sg3-utils`, which will contain a script that performs a scan of the system SCSI bus (appropriately called `rescan-scsi-bus.sh`). This should show up the reluctant LUN on your system. The other alternative would be to reboot. FWIW, a quick Googling showed up this issue on a Sourceforge site for the Linux SCSI subsystem. No resolution posted there, but you might find an additional idea or two: https://sourceforge.net/p/scst/mailman/message/24633514/

Comment: Even yum is not configured to install sg3 utils, If you check rescan-scsi-bus.sh it basically runs rescan,issue_lip etc which i already tried..Is there any way to avoid reboot?

Comment: Any more suggestions on this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any. Redhat's own documentation on this issue notes that `"echo '- - -' > /sys/class/scsi_host/hostX/scan should be enough to discover new Luns."` but also states that there are still problems with some SAN arrays (see https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2010-July/msg00079.html). You also might try the above command with your `issue_lip` invocation. That's all I've been able to find. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks thomas but that didn't help